# Python tornado AsyncHTTPClient fluke

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, tornado

I have a problem here:

```
import tornado.httpclient
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")

# inside a function
client = AsyncHTTPClient()
result = yield client.fetch('http://some-site.com/#hash?&key=value', raise_error=False)
print(result.effective_url) # prints: http://some.site/some/path/
```

Note that key-values go after hash. Some site that I scrape gives redirects like this. If I comment out "AsyncHTTPClient.configure('tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient')" that all works fine, but I cannot use proxy to intersect and view the HTTP exchanges. And with this line staff after hash disappears... Can Anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass `#fragment` part. It is used by browsers to navigate through anchors on page or client side routing (more info [rfc3985](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3986.txt) 3.5).

Fragment is not send to the server by browser. Also `libcurl` do not send the fragment part, [as doc says](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/4f037367ed69b77e14953fe88d8c0497782c0aab/docs/libcurl/opts/CURLOPT_URL.3#L281):

> While space is not typically a "legal" letter, libcurl accepts them.
>   When a user wants to pass in a '#' (hash) character it will be treated
>   as a fragment and get cut off by libcurl if provided literally. You
>   will instead have to escape it by providing it as backslash and its
>   ASCII value in hexadecimal: "\23".

You could replace `#` with `%23` as well, but the server should know how to handle it, more likely it does not since it is the part handled by a browser.

Comment: My link looks like this(changed : and . to | because otherwise this forum doesn't show it): http|//us-market|openx|com/#ready?&oauth_token=89eed5b7f568702616037623817362a471c7ddbbb8df19772708103e521261d5776d0a0f07f7ca149ca6c30205ab5792f0eccc207cf77147517509bc8f5fe57f0567a8c4d&oauth_verifier=5e2a2f7c9b Staff after # is important. If I use "AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")" my fetcher breaks breaks, even if I replace '#' with '%23'. The links come from redirection(302), in 'Location' header.

Comment: Staff after `#` is not important for you because destination server won't understand it. The auth is handled with javascript in the browser (file `http://us-market.openx.com/js/build/ox3.min.js`). You have to find different way to authenticate with openx oauth - they have some docs http://docs.openx.com/api/#api_authentication.html. If you don't want to use official API (not recommended) and scraping site I would use http://phantomjs.org/, but it is in js - node.js

Comment: Yeah, just looks how FireFox works, it doesn't send staff after #. I don't know why it's only working without CurlAsyncHTTPClient...

Comment: Your libcurl/client configuration might be messed up, because as I tested, the fragment has not been sent with simple client as well as curl client

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the `#` is called the "fragment", and it is not normally sent to the server. Instead, it is made available for the browser and javascript to use. At the level of HTTP, `http://some-site.com/#hash?&key=value` is equivalent to `http://some-site.com/`. `AsyncHTTPClient` should be stripping off the fragment whether you use curl or not; the difference you're seeing here is probably a bug.